# Combine object with different collation using Blender

Tags: blender

I'm using Blender to create a 3D model for a machine, i have created different collations of individual part of the machine, and use "Link" function to put them together, But how to combine them together? I tried to select them all, and press Ctrl+j, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Blenders [linked libraries](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/files/linked_libraries.html) allows you to duplicate an object in more than one file, with each duplicate reading the same object data from the library file. When the object is updated in the library file, every place it is duplicated will also be updated.

When you have an object linked into the current file you cannot modify the object's data in the current file, you need to do that in the library file.

If you don't want to join the objects in the original file, you can append the objects instead of linking them, this will copy the object data into the current file.

If you have already linked the objects, you can use [*Object->Relations->Make Local...*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/files/linked_libraries.html#make-local) to copy the objects into the current file where you can then join them together.